# Maintian list in list while filter out values

Tags: python, loops, nested-for-loop

Why does this loop not work?

```py
list = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
t=[]
for i in list:
  it=[]
  t.append(it)
  for j in x:
    if j==2:
    it.append(j)
```

would like `t=[[2],[2]]`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: the problem seems to be the mysterious `x` in the second for-loop, no? If it were `i` instead, the code should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your logic in every iteration of the outer `for` loop, you add an empty list `it` in `t` coz when the for loop start it initiate `it` as an empty list, and your code appends it in `t` and one more `syntex problem` is there in your code which is undefined `x` variable.

as per me the correct code for the desired output is:

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
t=[]
for i in list:
  it=[]
  for j in i:
    if j==2:
      it.append(j)
  t.append(it)
```

Comment: Thas code you wrote give says it missing indent. So it not working tried in two diffrent web pages for learing python

Comment: Its just indentation error , I just edit it, now tou can use it.

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: If you want you can accept this as answer for someone visit this question in future.

Comment: cant find an Accept button how do I accept

Comment: you can see a **write tick**  it below **vote down** button in answer.